# Filter on a Managed Property

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I'm using SharePoint 2019, the on-prem version (I'm coming from SharePoint 2010), and I am confused about the Highlighted content web part.  I

I'd like to show just News content, and then filter on a managed property that contains a department name (such as Marketing).

This is probably a dumb question, but I'd like to use the ContentType property for the department name.

The news articles are in a page library, created via the News web part.  Can I add a column to the library that would be used for the ContentType?